# bash - add blank line to heredoc via variable

Tags: bash, variable, cat, here-document

If I am using this scenario in a script:

```
#!/bin/bash

addvline=$(if [ "$1" ]; then echo "$1"; echo; fi)

cat << EOF
this is the first line
$addvline
this is the last line
EOF
```

if `$1` is emty I get a blank line.
But how can I add a blank line after `$1` for the case it is not emty?

So in the case running the script like:
`bash script.sh hello`

I would get:

```
this is the first line
hello

this is the last line
```

I tried to achieve this with using a second `echo` in the `if statement`, but the newline does not get passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let `if` decide to set your variable content not to use command substitution.

```
if [ "$1" ]; then addvline=$1$'\n'; fi
```

Then:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$1" ]; then addvline=$1$'\n'; fi
cat << EOF
this is the first line
$addvline
this is the last line
EOF
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several solutions to this. First, let's create a variable that contains a newline to be used later (in bash):

```
nl=$'\n'
```

then it could either be used to construct the variable to be printed:

```
#!/bin/bash
nl=$'\n'
if [ "$1" ]; then
    addvline="$1$nl"
else
    addvline=""
fi

cat << EOF
this is the first line
$addvline
this is the last line
EOF
```

Or you could avoid the `if` entirely if you use the correct parameter expansion:

```
#!/bin/bash
nl=$'\n'
addvline="${1:+$1$nl}"

cat << EOF
this is the first line
$addvline
this is the last line
EOF
```

Or, in one simpler code:

```
#!/bin/bash
nl=$'\n'

cat << EOF
this is the first line
${1:+$1$nl}
this is the last line
EOF
```